# Usage assert(not <condition>)

Tags: c++, assert, negation, preconditions

Reference: [std::is_sorted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted)

In the example section of the above link, I see the following usage:

```
    int data[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
    assert(not std::is_sorted(std::begin(data), std::end(data)));
```

I am familiar with the syntax `assert(! <condition>)`

Evidently, `assert(not <condition>)` is similar, but wanted to know whether it has been documented somewhere in the standard?

TIA

Vin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words "and", "or", and "not" are acceptable alternatives for the "&&", "||" and "!" operators in C++.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  I misread.